# Setting background image in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I currently have a silverlight application which rotates through several graphs of live data. Each page has two user controls though: one for an info box at the top and another for the graph to display. I have tried to add a background image to the master page that they are displayed on so that the image is behind everything but as soon as they load, they overwrite the image with their blank canvas.

So far attempts to make the background of the user controls transparent have had no effect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the background to be transparent on the host control itself, not just in the xaml files that get loaded. If you're using the object tag you would do something like:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="[your xap file]"/>
    <param name="background" value="transparent" />
         ....
</object>
```

Because the actual silverlight host control has a background color, if you don't set it to be transparent it will default to white which will overwrite your background regardless of if your canvas is transparent.

Answer (score 3):

It is now working perfectly. It needed

```
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

as well as setting the background to transparent.

Thanks for your help, it was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is surely something inside the user controls that has a white background, you could probably find it using Blend, or maybe using [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/). Spy is a great app that allows you to see the visual tree of a running app, among other things.